# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Showing convergence is easy, since for $x\geq 0$ we have $\sin x\leq x$ so:

$$0\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

I was wondering if it might have a closed form? Finding one is beyond me, but I am sure that the people on here will have ideas.

Comment: try Taylor expansion, you will get $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{(k-1)}}{(2k-1)!}\dfrac{1}{n^{2k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{(k-1)}}{(2k-1)!}\zeta(2k)$

Comment: My idea is that there is no reason to expect a closed form.

Answer (score 4):

The sum is approximately $1.47282823195618529629494738$. Plugging this into the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/) fails to find a match. Most likely, this has no closed form.

Comment: The 'algebraized' version $\sum\dfrac1n\sin\left(\dfrac\pi n\right)$ also seems to have no closed form - I get a value of roughly 1.6425614523 from the zeta method, and the ISC fails to find anything useful here either.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: What do you mean 'algebraized'? How did you compute that value?

Comment: 'algebraized' just in that all of the individual terms are algebraic (as opposed to the OP's original sum, which has all the terms transcendental); this doesn't mean anything particular, of course, but I was curious.  I computed it via the same Taylor expansion as mentioned in Yimin's comment to the original post - it's equal to the sum $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^k\pi^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\zeta(2k+2)$, and this converges quickly enough to evaluate to many places with Alpha.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Ah, I see the difference. You have $\pi^{2k+1}$ in yours, but Yimin doesn't.

Comment: Yimin's is the formula for $\sum\dfrac1n\sin(\dfrac1n)$; mine is the formula for $\sum\dfrac1n\sin(\dfrac\pi n)$ (as I said, the 'algebraized' version - I'm not expecting it to be the same value, of course, but was curious if it had a closed form either).  Both are correct for their respective sums.