# How to determine whether $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac1n\sin(\frac{1}{n})$ is convergent or divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to determine whether the series converges or diverges:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sin(\frac{1}{n})$$
I think here Limit Comparison Test should be applied but I am not sure how to start.

Comment: Related: [Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/324227)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two arguments :

1) As $n\to\infty$ :

$$\frac1n\sin\left(\frac1n\right)\sim\frac1{n^2}$$

and we know that the series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{n^2}}$ is convergent. Hence the convergence of $\displaystyle{\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1n\sin\left(\frac1n\right)}$

2) It is well know that :

$$\forall t\in[0,+\infty),\sin(t)\le t$$

Hence :

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N^\star},\,0\le\frac1n\sin\left(\frac1n\right)\le\frac1{n^2}$$which gives, by comparison, the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

From the Mean Value Theorem follows that there exist some $y_n\in(0,\tfrac1n)$ such that
$$\frac{\sin(\frac1n)-0}{\frac1n}=\cos(y_n)\leq 1$$
then $\sin (\frac1n)\le\frac1n$. And $$\tfrac1n\sin(\tfrac1n)\leq\tfrac1{n^2}$$

So the series is convergent from the comparison test.